# titanium how do i add a view to the single context

Tags: titanium

So i have a titanium app, and i just read about single contexts. (Incidentally, somebody here should write a book about programming in titanium... the only one out there doesn't really mention single contexts or any of that new-fangled stuff. Heck, make it an eBook. I'd buy it)

The titanium documentation stresses their use (http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Coding_Strategies-section-29004891_CodingStrategies-Executioncontexts) and  then politely forgets how to implement a single context!!

So, question:
Let's say i have the awesomeWidget page - this just shows a button, and when you click on a button a new screen appears.

The aswesomeWidget page is accessed  through another page - it is not from the root of the  titanium app.

Keeping to single contexts, how do i add the view that the button creates to the current window?

Do I:

keep a global pointer to the current (and only) window?

pass the variable holding the current window down to all the following pages that use it

something else?

Answer (score 1):

First off, Titanium keeps a reference to [your current window anyway for you, so this use case is easy](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI-property-currentWindow). For example:

```
awesomeWidgetButton.addEventListener('click' function(e) {
    var yourView = Ti.UI.createView({...});
    Titanium.UI.currentWindow.add(yourView);
});
```

If you want to dig further, the concept of a single context is closely tied to the use of CommonJS modules and the `require` keyword. It is very simple to keep a single context, just never open a window with the `url` component filled out, and liberally use the `require()` keyword. Other than that, its up to your imagination to keep track of who points to what and vice versa, there are standard patterns and [best practices](http://javascript.crockford.com) that apply here (MVC, Singletons, just keep it simple) just as in coding in any other language.